# Find the fraction that creates a repeating decimal that repeats certain digits

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, fractions, decimal-expansion

Is there any way to find the fraction $x/y$ that, when converted to a decimal, repeats a series of digits $z$? For example: ${x}/{y} = z.zzzzzzzz...$ or with actual numbers, $x/y = 234.234234234...$ (z is 234)

If this is impossible, is there a way that does the same but the value to the left of the decimal is not $z$?

Comment: Please update the tags if necessary. I don't know what the proper ones would be.

Comment: _Another hint:_ $x/y-x/(1000y) = 234$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a nice fact (derived from the expression demonstrated by TonyK): The repeating decimal $0.zzz\dots$ can be represented by 
$$\frac{z}{10^{l(z)}-1}$$
where $l(z)$ here denotes the number of digits of $z$.

Now if we want instead $z.zzz\dots$, all we have to do is multiply the above expression by $10^{l(z)}$ (or as Joffan points out - simply add $z$), getting
$$\frac{10^{l(z)}z}{10^{l(z)}-1}$$

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way that does not involve yet another formula for students (or you) to memorize. (I am not against formulas; I just realize that many people are.)

The idea is to multiply the number by a power of ten that gets the same repeating pattern, then subtract. For your example,

\begin{align*}
u & =234.234\ldots\\
1000u & =234234.234\ldots\\
999u & =234.234\ldots-234234.234\ldots\\
& =234000\\
u & =\frac{234000}{999}\\
& =\frac{26000}{111}
\end{align*}